# Can I install windows which comes with rc730 laptop (on its hard drive) on secondary disk which I will add to this laptop?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, operating-systems

I plan to bought secondary disk (SSD) and add it to my rc730 laptop (my laptop has 2 slots for hard drives, so it is not a problem). I want to place Windows on secondary disk, SSD, which will be much faster than 5400 rpm stock hard drive. How can I do this, so I don't need to buy Windows? Main question is - can I install windows which comes with my laptop to another disk? Does Samsung allow this?

**UPDATE:**

Check your laptops box - you have there DVD "System Recovery Media". :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samsung really doesn't care what hard drive you install to.

Think about it this way.  What if the original hard drive crashed and had to be replaced.  You'd be reinstalling Windows on another hard drive, right?

So.  Here is the easy way to do this.

Step One.

- Read the manual for your laptop.  Get to know your hardware.  This is always important.  For example... is [this your laptop](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/model/NP-RC730-S02AT)? Because there is a downloadable manual right there.  In chapter 4 they describe the tools that Samsung provides for backing up your system.  Unfortunately, in your specific case, unless you were provided with System Restore Media (as per the end of chapter 4), there is no procedure described in your manual for reinstalling Windows onto another hard drive.  Which means you would have to A) attempt to clone your existing installation onto the SSD or B) contact Samsung and purchase the System Recovery Media for your system or C) **try** the backup procedure described in chapter 4 and see if you can restore the backup onto the SSD after performing Step 2 below and **BEFORE** you erase the original drive.

Step Two.

- Remove the existing hard drive, and put the SSD in the slot it occupied.  Boot to the recovery media, and perform the factory recovery procedure reinstalling Windows onto the SSD.

Step Three.

- Put the original hard drive into the second hard drive slot.  Boot the computer and erase it however you like.

Now... you can edit step one, and change it to where you make a backup of your existing installation... but you'd be better off with the factory recovery.

**EDIT** as to your update... WHY??!?  Why would you just pull the drive and swap it out without having ANY discs to work with to reinstall Windows?  At this point, based on the fact that you just did this, I'm not sure you are qualified to do the job.

Comment: @SuitUp Samsung provided the "Samsung Recovery Solution", which has the option of essentially deleting everything from your C drive, and reinstalling Windows 7 fresh as if the laptop was brand new.  However the manual I found for your laptop does NOT give the option for creating recovery discs.

Comment: To your edit: don't worry, I'm gonna use System Recovery Media from DVD. I wasn't aware I have any dvd with this software at all, because I'm not in the town at the moment, so I couldn't check. And why I start laptop like that? Before your update I misunderstood your answer and thought Samsung store Windows copy and recovery software on some kind built-in memory chip. Sure, it would be uncommon, but I saw stranger things... :) My whole point of this question was this: someone who have Samsung will know I have such DVD or I can choose partition to where I can install Windows and just tell me.:)